# How to enter a value in a textbox (nested in a HTML table which is in a form) and also pass it to a Javascript function

Tags: javascript, forms, jsp, html-table, textbox

I have a JSP and an ArrayList of a bean is accessed to populate a HTML table with details of products. The table also displays a "Quantity" textbox, which when filled in by the user, should transfer the value to a JS function. The JS function in turn should calculate the total price("Qty" * "Unit Price")  for the product. I am trying to access the "Quantity" textbox and get its value onChange, but I only get null or undefined. I have tried many solutions available online(particularly SO), but this is not working. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

My code looks like this:

JS code

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function calculateTotalPrice(tbval) {

 var t = tblContents.getElementsByTagName('qtyText')[0];
     alert("total qty is :" +t);
 var x = tblContents.getElementsByTagName('price')[0];
     alert("price is :" +x);
 var y = t*x;
 var h = tblContents.getElementsByTagName('totalPrice')[0];
 h.value = y;
alert("price set")
</script>
```

The JSP code

```
<table>
 <c:forEach items="${beanListInServlet1}" var= "exBean">
    <form action="ExampleServlet" method = "post" name = "tableForm">
       <input type="hidden" name="Id" value= "<c:out Value = "${exBean.Id}"/>"  />

<tr>         
      <td>
        <c:out Value = "${exBean.price}"/>            
      </td>

      <td>
        <input name = "qtyText" type = "textbox" size = "2"  defaultValue = "0" onChange         
          = "calculateTotalPrice()"/>
      </td>

      <td>
         <input name ="price" type = "hidden" value= "<c:out Value = "${exBean.price}"/>"  />
         <input name = "totalprice" type = "textbox" border = "0" size = "2" defaultValue    
           = "0" />          
      </td>
   </c:forEach>  
  </form>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass *this* into your function call, ala

```
 calculateTotalPrice(this)


 here is some addition info:



  function calculateTotalPrice(tbval) {

 myForm = document.forms[0];
 txtEntry = tbval.value;// or myForm.elements["name"].value
        alert("total qty is :" + txtEntry);
    var x = myForm.elements["price"].value
        alert("price is :" +x);
    var y = txtEntry*x;
    var h = tblContents.getElementsByTagName('totalPrice')[0];
  //  h.value = y;
  //  alert("price set")
```

Comment: Part of this solution worked and the other part did not. What worked? : txtEntry has the value. However, the value for the input type with name "price" was undefined. I did try some changes to the input tag, but that did not work either.                                                                 <input type ="hidden" name ="price" value ="${regBean.price}"/>